# How to write marketplace web project documentation?

Tags: html, wordpress, documentation, manuals

When creating web projects (mostly XHTML/WORDPRESS THEMES) for sale on any given marketplace, what is the best way to go about writing technical manuals for users?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a programming question, but...

Generally the best way to teach is to explain things. Figure out what the basic functions of the site are, and what users are likely to do & explain them. Look at other people's manuals for ideas on what to do & copy that for your project.